# KIE server not appearing below Remote server in KIE workbench (v7.53.0.Final w/ WildFly19.10.Final)

Tags: workbench, kie, drools-kie-server, kie-server

Please help with this problem.

1. Problem summary
   I'm trying to setup the KIE workbench and KIE server to work with DRL rules.
   I'm able to setup both by following this link. http://www.mastertheboss.com/bpm/jbpm6/installing-the-business-central-on-wildfly/.
   Both (WB & kie server) work well separately.

Problem :  Couldn't view the KIE Server under "remote servers" in the workbench. This stops the DRL rules from getting executed. No visible errors on server logs.
[IMAGE Attach: Workbench-deploymentUnit-Remote server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwG0o.png)

2. I used business-central-7.53.0.Final-wildfly19.war and kie-server-7.53.0.Final-ee7.war & placed them in wildfly-dist-19.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments folder. Both are successfully deployed. NO BLOCKING errors.
   Workbench URL: http://localhost:8080/business-central-7.53.0.Final-wildfly19/kie-wb.jsp
   KIE server endpoint: http://localhost:8080/kie-server-7.53.0.Final-ee7/services/rest/server
   [IMAGE Attach: kie-server rest endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egvrl.png)

I have used the below command to start Wildfly server

wildfly-19.1.0.Final\bin> standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.server.user=kieserver02 -Dorg.kie.server.pwd=kieserver02!@ -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server-7.53.0.Final-ee7/services/rest/server -Dorg.server.controller.user=kieuser01 -Dorg.server.controller.pwd=kieuser01!@ -Dorg.kie.server.controller.location=http://localhost:8080/business-central-7.53.0.Final-wildfly19/rest/controller -Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver